# Sorting lists with mixed int and strings

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to code some tombala game. Here is my code.

```
self.player1_cards = [
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), ''],
        [random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91)],
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91),
            '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91)]
    ]
    self.player2_cards = [
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), ''],
        [random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91)],
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91),
            '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91)]
    ]
```

I'm creating the users cards like this. After that I'm trying to sort the all integers ascending order. However when I tried that:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
        self.player1_cards[i].sort()
        self.player2_cards[i].sort()

    print("Player1:\n", self.player1_cards,
          "\nPlayer 2:\n", self.player2_cards)
```

I'm getting an error like this:

```
self.player1_cards[i].sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I understand why this happens but I cant figure how to sort this list. Can you please help me?

Comment: Why have the strings in your list in the first place? What purpose do they serve?

Comment: This is the template for this game. I mean these places have to be empty. You can see the figure in this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/recn3h

Comment: I think you could just replace the strings with zeros. Since 0 is not included in `random.randint(1, 91)`, it will mean "invalid value". That will let you compare integers too integers.

Comment: @ForceBru But how does that keep the zeros in place?

Comment: `random.randint` is probably not what you want for this, since there's a chance a single card can have 2 of the same number. You probably want [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: i think both can have the same number

Comment: @ForceBru but if i use 0, it will sort 0s too. ' ' these are representing the empty spaces.

Comment: @sonelektrikci, well, right now you're attempting to sort _everything_, including empty spaces. What do you actually need to sort?

Comment: Are those lines in the `__init__` method?

Comment: @ForceBru because of ' ' these, im getting an error and i cant sort the lists.

Comment: @wwii no, in another function.

Comment: @sonelektrikci, yes, of course - it's not possible to compare strings to integers. The question is whether you want the empty spaces to stay in the same places and sort stuff outside the empty spaces, or sort absolutely everything, as you're trying to do here?

Comment: yes im trying to do what you say. The empty spaces will stay where they are and will sort the other datas.

Comment: When you access/use the cards should they always be sorted?

Comment: Yes. Everytime i create a new card, it has to be sorted. @wwii

Answer (score 2):

Creating an example row with your code for the first row:

```
>>> import random
>>> row = [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), '']
>>> row
[79, '', 78, '', 57, '', 54, '', 84, 26, '']
```

Extracting and sorting the numbers, then using them at the places for numbers:

```
>>> ordered = iter(sorted(x for x in row if x != ''))
>>> [next(ordered) if x != '' else '' for x in row]
[26, '', 54, '', 57, '', 78, '', 79, 84, '']
```

But instead of building it unsorted, taking it apart, and rebuilding it sorted, it would be simpler to just build it sorted in the first place.

Comment: do i have to sort them row by row?

Comment: Well, that's what your code is trying to do. Whether that's the right thing to do, I don't know. It's your question, not mine.

Comment: no i mean is there a way to sort all rows in the self.player1_cards and self.player2_cards

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I showed how to sort one line, you already know how to loop, so... just do it?

Comment: for i in range(0, 3):
            ordered = iter(sorted(x for x in self.player1_cards[i] if x != ' '))
            [next(ordered) if x != '' else '' for x in self.player1_cards[i]]     I used this loop but i get the same error

Comment: @sonelektrikci You used `' '` instead of `''`.

Comment: i found the solution thanks to you :) i added answer

Answer (score 0):

If it fits your use case you can sort the numbers when you make the cards then they will not need to be sorted later.  Use a function external to the class to create cards. Create the numbers first; sort them; then add the placekeepers.

```
def cards():
    nrows, ncols = 3,6
    a = []
    for _ in range(nrows):
        numbers = [random.randint(1, 91) for _ in range(ncols)]
        numbers.sort()
        numbers = iter(numbers)
        indices = {1,3,5,7,10}
        row = [next(numbers) if i not in indices else '' for i in range(11)]

        a.append(row)
    return a


class F:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def other(self):
        self.player1_cards = cards()
        self.player2_cards = cards()

f = F()
f.other()
```

---

If you cannot change the way the cards are made - write a function that will strip the placekeepers; sort the numbers; put the placekeepers back in.

```
def sort_cards(cards):
    new_cards = []
    indices = {1,3,5,7,10}
    for row in cards:
        row = [n for n in row if n != '']
        row.sort()
        row = iter(row)
        new_row = [next(row) if i not in indices else '' for i in range(11)]
        new_cards.append(new_row)
    return new_cards
```

Comment: I am sorry but i didnt understand the code. How can i implement this to my cards.

Comment: @sonelektrikci - The first shows a method that sorts them when they are made so there would be no need to sort them after they are *used*. The second shows a method to sort them IF they were NOT sorted when they were made. You would only need one of the methods. I imagine that *creating* a sorted list of cards would be most beneficial and the second method would not be needed but I did not know the entirety of your circumstance so I included the second just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Heap Overflow, I find the solution.

```
self.player1_cards = [
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), ''],
        [random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91)],
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91),
         '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91)]
    ]
    self.player2_cards = [
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), ''],
        [random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91)],
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91),
            '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91)]
    ]
```

I created the card like this. After that :

```
    for i in range(0, 3):
        ordered = iter(sorted(x for x in self.player1_cards[i] if x != ''))
        self.player1_cards[i] = [
            next(ordered) if x != '' else '' for x in self.player1_cards[i]]

    for j in range(0, 3):
        ordered1 = iter(
            sorted(x for x in self.player2_cards[j] if x != ''))
        self.player2_cards[j] = [
            next(ordered1) if x != '' else '' for x in self.player2_cards[j]]
```

With these loop i get what i want. This is the result:

```
Player1:
[[3, '', 4, '', 40, '', 50, '', 62, 75, ''], [4, 17, '', 33, '', 36, '', 38, 72], [17, '', 51, '', 56, '', 63, '', 64]]
Player 2:
 [[14, '', 32, '', 39, '', 77, '', 86, 87, ''], [17, 49, '', 61, '', 62, '', 71, 89], [12, '', 13, '', 50, '', 74, '', 80]]
```